# Android resource compilation failed

Tags: java, android, gradle, aapt

I am developing an android app where I am in need of design support library so when I add `implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'` into my build.gradle(app) then the following error appears:

> Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
>   MyAppDirectory\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2489: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/itemBackground' with config ''.

But when I remove the dependency `implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'`
then the error disappears and gradle build successfully.

My Project build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
  //        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha04'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
     }
 }

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()


   }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "myapplicationid"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
   }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

//third party libraries
implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.2.2'

implementation 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
implementation 'com.chaos.view:pinview:1.4.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
}
```

**Note: I have already cleaned and rebuilded the project and I have also invalidated and cleared the cache**

Comment: Do you have itemBackground attribute ?

Comment: Try to upgrade gradle and SDK.

Comment: @matio I have added some background attribute to toolbars and buttons but not something like itemBackground attribute

Comment: @grrigore I have updated everything but still, it shows the same error when I add the design library

Comment: Have you tried Invalidate cache and restart?

Comment: @EhsanMashhadi Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing some research, I found that MenuView (The Menu in the Toolbar) has defined this attribute.

```
<declare-styleable name="MenuView">
    ...
    <!-- Default background for each menu item. -->
    <attr name="itemBackground" format="color|reference" />
    ...
</declare-styleable>
```

I have used `<attr name="android:itemBackground" />` instead of
`<attr name="itemBackground" format="reference|color" />` to fix this issue.

Please upgrade to version 1.4.1.

Answer (score 2):

Check for an apostrophe (') for any string value in arrays.xml or strings.xml and make sure you add a backslash(\) before it

Example 1:
`<string-array> <item>example's</item> </string-array>`

to

`<string-array> <item>example\'s</item> </string-array>`

Example 2:
`<string>example's</string>`

to

`<string>example\'s</string>`

Comment: I missed that point. Your answer helped. Great!

Answer (score 1):

It seems one of the libraries you have used have the same name attribute with support library. I suggest you start exclude them starting from espresso, then see if you can fix it, and continuously set this to other libraries until you find which library have used it.

```
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```

Comment: Thanks, It was due to pinview library so what if I want to use pinview library and design library both.

Comment: @mdadil2019 do this for your pinview implementation as well, if doesnt work then you can always post issue on their github page, I tried looking at the issues on their github page but nothing like this..

Comment: @AalapPatel ok, I have reported the issue

Comment: Ok but if you have marked this as answer then is there still any issue ???

Answer (score 0):

In my case error appeared because for a view that generated error,
there was excessive xml namespace definition
,that is : `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/sb_swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

When Android Studio is building, error appears :

```
Android resource compilation failed
C:\dev\hyperoptic.infinity\mobile-fit\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\stripped.dir\layout\activity_spine_build_job_report.xml:29: error: duplicate attribute.
C:\dev\hyperoptic.infinity\mobile-fit\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\stripped.dir\layout\activity_spine_build_job_report.xml: error: file failed to compile.
```

This means that we need to delete xmlns, as in compiled xml it appears in three places !

So, deleting `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` resolved this problem.